# Extra 2 DB9 pins connection

Tags: ground, chassis, db9

Many DB9 symbols have 2 additional pins other than the 9 signal and GND pins that they are known for. How and to what are these 2 pins connected ? Pins 10 and 11.

[image]

Is it connected to chassis ground or is it an NC just to provide more stability for the mechanical and vibration protection?

Comment: I would not show pins 10 and 11 on the schematic, but they would appear as mounting holes in the PCB footprint.  They may or may not be grounded, depending on the style of connector you use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

They're the two sets of pins leading downwards on the sides of the connector.

> Is it connected to chassis ground or is it an NC just to provide more stability for the mechanical and vibration protection?

Yes. That is to say, they are always for mechanical stability, and sometimes for chassis ground when the application calls for it.

Comment: When should it be connected to chassis ground ?

Comment: When the application calls for it.

Comment: Could you kindly give an example please ?

Comment: There are too many applications out there to give examples.